# How to pass values to query externally

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elk

I have below similar logs.

I have created dummy `index` and created `mapping` like below in `dev-tools`

```
PUT new
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and `indexed` data as below,

```
PUT /new/_doc/1
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-11-05 08:12:14.534",
  "level": "INFO",
  "id": "1",
  "text": "website is accessed",
  "status": "clicked"
}

PUT /new/_doc/2
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-10-14 09:11:14.534",
  "level": "INFO",
  "id": "3",
  "text": "website is accessed",
  "status": "clicked"
}

PUT /new/_doc/3
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-09-09 02:08:20.534",
  "level": "INFO",
  "id": "4",
  "text": "website is accessed",
  "status": "clicked"
}
```

I am able to fetch the total counts using below `request` query,

```
GET new/_search
{
  "aggs": {},
  "size": 0,
  "fields": [],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "text": "website is accessed"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2021-10-01",
              "lte": "2021-10-30"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

Getting `response` as below,

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

As you see, i need to `hardcode` the `date` to fetch the value for a particular `month` i.e to fetch the same information for `sept` month, I need to modify the `date time range` as below in curl request,

```
"range": {
  "@timestamp": {
    "gte": "2021-09-01",
    "lte": "2021-09-30"
    }
    }
```

Below is the `curl call request`.

```
curl -u elastic:xxx  -XGET "http://10.10.10.10:9200/new/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "aggs": {},
  "size": 0,
  "fields": [],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "text": "website is accessed"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2021-10-01",
              "lte": "2021-10-30"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}'
```

How can I pass `year` and `month` dynamically (i.e without actually hardcoding it request itself) to the curl request which will fetch the information for that particular `month`, `year`?

---

update -

I am able to get the results for last month (Nov) or last 2 months (Oct) and so on using below,

last month -  `Nov` -

```
"gte": "now-M",
"lt": "now/M"
```

2 months  - `Oct`

```
"gte": "now-2M/M",
"lte": "now-2M/M"
```

But is there way to provide desired `year` and `month` to retrieve results?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/common-options.html#date-math) with fully defined dates:

```
"range": {
  "@timestamp": {
    "gte": "2021-10-01",
    "lte": "2021-10-01||+1M/d"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ok but again in that case, the single curl request can't be used i.e for every new month to get the data of last month, I need to change the timestamp in the curl request i.e for current month Dec, if i have to fetch the data for Nov, then i need to change the `month` in the timestamp and same will have to do when Jan will be the current month and I need to fetch the data for Dec month. Soon i need to change the year also. so this this is not good. I don't want to create separate curl requests for every month, hence i am looking, if I can pass the year and month not via hardcoded way?

Comment: How do you run that `curl`? If it's a bash script you could use bash scripting: `YEAR=2010; MONTH=10; curl ... "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte": "$YEAR-$MONTH-01", "lte": "$YEAR-$MONTH-01||+1M/d" } }` ?

Comment: I was running curl as is i.e exactly the same way i have pasted above (without bash script etc..) but yes including this curl in bash script and providing year and month as an variable can be a good option. I will try this. Thanks